# Open FileStreamResult by ajax (as downloaded file)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to use an ajax call to open FileStreamResult as a downloaded file?

Controller method

```
public FileStreamResult DownloadPDF()
{
        var stream = myHandler.getFileStream("myfile.pdf");
        return File(stream, "application/pdf", "myfile.pdf"));
}
```

Html code

```
<a href="#" class="mydownload">Click Me</a>
<script type="text/javascript>
    $("a.mydownload").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://myserver/file/DownloadPDF',
            success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                var blob = new Blob([data], { type: "application/pdf" })
                var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.href = url;
                a.click();

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Running on IE I get access denied, but on Chrome it runs fine. I do however get a "blank"/invalid pdf.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `XMLHttpRequest()` with `responseType` set to `"blob"`, add `download` attribute to `<a>` element

```
$("a.mydownload").click(function () {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.responseType = "blob";
        request.open("GET", "http://myserver/file/DownloadPDF");
        request.onload = function() {
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.href = url;
            a.download = this.response.name || "download-" + $.now()
            a.click();
        }
        request.send();
});
```

alternatively, you can use [jquery-ajax-blob-arraybuffer.js](https://gist.github.com/codler/8842432). See also [Add support for HTML5 XHR v2 with responseType set to 'arraybuffer' on $.ajax](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11461)

Comment: This works great on Chrome, but in IE I get access denied on a.click()

Comment: IE11. I first got a InvalidStateError on request.responseType="blob", but moving that line after request.open solved that issue. You may want to update your code accordingly. Now it's the a.click() access denied issue I am struggling with

Comment: It seems the download method is not supported in IE11

Answer (score 3):

Still had issues with IE11, but a minor change to @guest271314 solutions, seems to do the trick.

1. Set responseType after open.
2. Use msSaveBlob on IE

```
$("a.mydownload").click(function() {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", "http://myserver/file/DownloadPDF");
  request.responseType = "blob";
  request.onload = function() {
    var msie = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE");
    if (msie > 0) {
      window.navigator.msSaveBlob(this.response, "myfile.pdf");
    } else {
      var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
      var a = document.createElement("a");
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.href = url;
      a.download = this.response.name || "download-" + $.now()
      a.click();
    }
  }
  request.send();
});
```

Comment: This works in a development environment. In production, I'm getting a "failed to load document" error anytime I try opening the pdf document.

Please how do I resolve this?