# Get FileStreamResult using ajax asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, filestream, filestreamresult

I had a function in controller named Export

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Export")]
    public async Task<FileStreamResult> Export(int a)
    {
        var fileStream = new MemoryStream();
        var contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

        return new FileStreamResult(fileStream, contentType);
    }
```

I called this function from the view using ajax.

```
  $('#GetDetails').click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Export", "ExportNow")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {a:1},
                success: function (result) {
                    alert('Success.');
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert('Failed to Export.');
                }
            });
        });
```

how i can open the FileStreamResult returned from the Export function (download file).
Anyone please help.

Comment: Quite similar to what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37462263/open-filestreamresult-by-ajax-as-downloaded-file

Comment: his one was on pdf format and i need is xlsx format and his function is returning a file and i am returning a filestreamresult

Comment: i had tried that solution but it is not works for me, my function is taking in a parameter.

Answer (score -2):

This works for me:

```
$('#GetDetails').click(function () {
    window.open('controlleraction/document?id=xx', '_blank');
});
```

Comment: The question asked for an ajax call